# What does pre-damped mean in the pre-damped switched-inductor piezoelectric energy-harvesting charger

Tags: schematics, energy-harvesting

There is a paper from the IEEE,title:Optimally Pre-Damped Switched-Inductor Piezoelectric Energy-Harvesting Charger,and the author show two kind of pre-damped: symmetry and asymmetry,shown as fig 1 and fig 2.

[image]
[image]

And now i want to ask what does "pre-damped" mean in his pre-damped switched-inductor piezoelectric energy-harvesting charger?i know the damp  means that any vibration system in vibration, due to external effects or the system itself is inherently caused by the gradual decrease in vibration amplitude characteristics,but what is "pre"-damp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The harder  i press the PZT,the stronger electrical damping forece PZT produce,that is , the current source produce the stronger current ,and before we want to know what is predamp,we have to know there are a equivalent current source and  capacitor in the PZT equivalent circuit.

"No predamp" means the current source charge the equivalent capacitor,just simple!

"predamp" means the outside circuit charge this equivalent capacitor first,then the current source charge the equivalent capacitor to the higher or lower voltage.

Answer (score 2):

### Simple answer:

It means adding electrical alternating LC tuned DC switched voltage capacitance to a mechanical induced capacitor (piezo) oscillating square wave current pump that generates only 33uW and boost it > 700% in power.

A really long answer

This is an electro-mechanical dynamic impedance matching scheme. It boosts the energy harvesting from 33uW by 780% from gains in efficent energy conversion with 1 Ω ESR at V<20V. THe voltage gain <10 is stored energy but the impedance matching improves coupling efficiency. This matching is performed by the switched partly resonant LC capacitive DC voltage applied returned as current from the end-stop cantelever "jerk" on the crystal. (Jerk is a unit of measure for rate of change of acceleration)

**[REF](http://rincon-mora.gatech.edu/publicat/cnfs/new16_pzdamp.pdf)**
[image]
This PZT piezo-electric energy harvesting chip that is a switched charge current source in a vibration mode with end stops that applies small square waves.  By synchronously applying a pre-charge voltage, the PZT can dump  more power thru the action of stepped current.

Essentially it means a precharged capacitance voltage is applied to the piezo cantelever transducer so that greater mechanical piezo energy transfer efficiency can be performed.  This is based on matching the impedance of a switched discrete capacitance voltage ( and some inductive current) to a mechanically excited alternating Norton current source and thus mechanical energy is absorbed by the dwitched electrical capacitance.

When this occurs,  pre-charging the crystal C(pz) to some applied Vpd(pre-damp v) between half cycles allows both end stops of the cantelever mounting to have higher DC voltage charges switched.  In other words Vpd raises the damping force against which motion supplies power, which in turn allows more energy to be harvested.

Basically it is improving energy transfer by matching the impedance of the mechanical alternating step force with an electrical alternating step load impedance to maximize the rms P(pzt) = current * square wave voltage by synchronous impedance matching to a square wave mechanical-to electrical current source.

So a switched Vpd cap load collects more energy from a "pico-bang-bang" ( my terminology) alternating cantelever PZT current source.  THis must be matched and optimized as component ESR*I^2 losses rise exponentially with gains from pre-dampening voltages applied.

What I'm not sure about yet is the optimal LC resonant frequency vs the mechanical vibration range of frequencies and the ratio of Cpc/Cpz.  THe other thing not stated is how this affects the longevity or reliablity of the crystal.

### Anecdotal

As I know from previous car experience, if replacement shock absorbers are too stiff, the McPherson strut popped thru the hood (bonnet) of my Audi CD5000 Turbo on a washboard road.  Exceptionally "smooth" but self-destructive.

Comment: Thankyou sir,but there are still something i didn't understand,i hope you can give me some clue

Comment: About the first part of long answer,you said this is an electro-mechanical dynamic impedance matching scheme.it boost efficiency by matching a 1 ohm resistor.Do you have something basic knowledge or formula about this to help me really understand why it can boost efficiency by a resistor?

Comment: About the second part below the "REF",i agree that precharged capacitance voltage is applied to the piezo cantelever transducer so that greater mechanical piezo energy transfer efficiency can be performed.But i can't understand why

Comment: pre-charging the crystal C(pz) to some applied Vpd(pre-damp v),which raises the damping force against which motion supplies power, which in turn allows more energy to be harvested.but it seems that it doesn't have relation with pre-damp,because in most of case,this "pre" means do something in advance,or this "pre" doesn't mean "in advance"?

Comment: ESR of 1 Ohm must be minimize to improve efficiency , as energy lost is Pd=I^2*ESR  which is the DC resistance of the resonator coil. Think of it like Active Power Factor correction to convert stored energy ( spring mass cantelever) into real energy by "conjugate impedance matching" <<< lookup...  this  "pre-charge" is the alternating DC phase compensation ( which is actually AC)

Comment: Sir,about the first question,thanks for your explaination . The second question,i surf the internet for "conjugate impedance matching",but didn't see what i want.The third answer you said,it seems there is no relation with my third question

Comment: About the third question ,i want to ask, is that the title of this paper is about optimally pre-damped,so the paper must said something about "pre-damped",but how do this"predamped" come from?Where is "damp" from?i didn't see anything about damp, not to mention "pre-damp"

Comment: Damped usually means like a shock absorber but tuned to the frequency expected with the spring and mass.  My 1st web hit gave a perfect title "Piezoelectric Energy Harvesting Improvement with Complex Conjugate Impedance Matching "  which i did not buy, so I searched for the title instead and found many similar http://metal.shanghaitech.edu.cn/publication/C6.pdf  you can learn how to find things faster this way. Shocks have been absorbing energy in cars for 100 yrs.

Comment: @Sir how to upload the paper to the question?,just like your "REF"

Comment: post link without http: if you do not have enough credits